# Eclipse RCP : How can I change font size for a Terminal view

Tags: eclipse-rcp, font-size, eclipse-plugin

I have added a Terminal view in my RCP Application and i want to change the font size of the terminal view when user re-size the window. is it possible? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: while this is interesting, it violates the user preference guidelines. If the user is interested in seeing a larger font, they can set the font size preference for that view. However, if they set the font size, then you change it, the user will be completely confused.

Comment: yes i agree. but that is another issue. for now i need to accomplish this task. if you have any idea that will be helpful :)

Comment: we will have a toggle button on the view and  font re-size will only happen if the toggle button is on. that's mean user will not be confused.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of console have you added ? The IOConsole has `setFont()` method. You can listen for changes like this:

```
    parent.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(final Event e) {
            System.out.println(parent.getSize());
           //here change the font size
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am using TM-terminal-2.0    http://www.eclipse.org/tm/  i have tried using your code. it did not work.

Comment: code is too big. i think we have to  work with the jface font registry. fist get the current terminal font from the font regestry and then update the font size and put back the font to font regestry